# Mysql при выборке объединить данные по условию, нужна помощь в запросе

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Приветствую, нужна ваша помощь, есть база:

**users**

```
   ID   |  name        | 
--------|--------------|
 1      | админ        |
 2      | пользователь |
 3      | вася         |
```

**user_groups_map**

```
    ID  |  user_id   |  group_id | 
--------|------------|-----------|
 1      |  1         |  4        |
 2      |  2         |  3        |
 3      |  1         |  3        |
 4      |  2         |  2        |
```

**user_groups**

```
    ID  |  rank      | group_name    | 
--------|------------|---------------|
 1      |  1         | Первый год    |
 2      |  10        | Второй год    |
 3      |  40        | Руководитель  |
 4      |  100       | Разработчик   |
```

Стояла задача допустим выбрать пользователей с группой у которой роль 40, запрос я составил и он справляется с этой задачей

```
SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(ug.group_name) as groups,
 MAX(ug.rank) as ranks,  
u.id as uid,    
u.name  
FROM 
 users  u  
INNER JOIN 
 user_groups_map ugm
 ON ugm.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN 
 user_groups ug
 ON ug.id = ugm.group_id    
WHERE ug.rank = '40'
   GROUP BY u.id
```

и вывод получаем такой

```
groups       |  ranks  |  uid  |  name
-------------|---------|-------|--------------
Руководитель | 40      |  1    | Админ
Руководитель | 40      |  2    | Пользователь
```

но есть одно НО:

**нужно что бы в ranks и groups были добавлены данные о том что эти пользователи состоят и в другой группе в случае юзера Админ это разработчик
и в groups должны быть все названия групп в которых состоит юзер, а в ranks максимальный ранг.**
т.е вывод должны получить примерно такой

[image: нужные вывод]

возможно ли как то это сделать? или штатными средствами не выйдет? 
нужна подсказка или сам запрос!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: подклейте user_groups_map и user_groups еще раз скажем как ugm1 и  ug1 с точно такими же условиями `ON`, но без условий фильтрации в `where`. И используйте именно их в формировании полей `GROUP_CONCAT(ug1.group_name) as groups,
 MAX(ug1.rank) as ranks`

Comment: да, получилось, огромное спасибо, я и не знал что можно еще раз использовать таблицы!